# Highchart display single entry against each category in bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on `highchart`. I am trying to build a bar chart with a single entry against each category. Right now I am working on an example [basic-bar](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic). Below is the output

[image]

**Expected Output**

I want a single entry against each category. For example against `April`, I want only one bar not multiple and so on

[image]

Here is the working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic)

Comment: itsnot very clear what you want, because, if you click on legend you hide or show the differents bars.. so you just use the parameter visible inside data to hide or not the bar.. see my answer

Comment: So basically you are just interested in something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fr02ohxd/

Comment: @madepiet yes exactly

Comment: so i understant you want a drill chart, so what do you want as result from your sample? could you be more concrete?

Comment: @Frenchy no I don't want drill down. Just want to display single entry against each single category

Comment: sorry i misunderstand you... in this case just delete the data you dont want..and the chart will be displayed with only one bar? i dont understant where is the difficulty for you.. i have set comment all charts except one in my snippet modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just use the parameter `visible`:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 80,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || '#FFFFFF',
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [
    /*{
        visible: false,
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
    }, {
        visible: false,
        name: 'Year 1900',
        data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
    }, {
        visible: false,
        name: 'Year 2000',
        data: [814, 841, 3714, 727, 31]
    }, */
    {
        visible: true,
        name: 'Year 2016',
        data: [1216, 1001, 4436, 738, 40]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Bar chart showing horizontal columns. This chart type is often
        beneficial for smaller screens, as the user can scroll through the data
        vertically, and axis labels are easy to read.
    </p>
</figure>
```

Comment: It's not actually what I want. The expected output image is just to give an idea. Don't go in the same color. See the comment of @madepiet that's what I want